# Retornar curl com JSON

Tags: php, json, libcurl

Bom dia, eu estou tentando retornar esse código em JSON, eu só quero alguns campos especificos ex: Operadora, tipo, portabilidade e estado.

```
<?php

//header('Content-type: application/json');
$post = ['tel' => $_GET['enviar'] , 'bto' => 'submit'];

$ch = curl_init('http://consultanumero.info/consulta');

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'http://consultanumero.info/consulta',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
    ],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS
]); 
//json_encode($ch);
echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Esse é meu código e o retorno:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Consulta NÃºmero</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="519584384854184" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css?1409782940" media="all" />
    <link rel="prerender" href="http://consultanumero.info/" />
    <script src="/js/base.js?1407968504" async></script>
    <script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" async></script>
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,"script","//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");
        ga("create", "UA-16052289-33", "auto");
        ga("send", "pageview");
    </script>
</head>

<body class="int consulta">

<div id="geral">
<div id="cab">
    <h1><a href="/">Consulta NÃºmero</a></h1>
    <p>Descubra a operadora atual de qualquer nÃºmero, celular ou telefone fixo!</p>
</div>



<div id="ctd">
    <div class="prop">
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block" data-analytics-uacct="UA-16052289-33" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3806187316222201" data-ad-slot="9873102520"></ins>
        <script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>
    </div>

    <div class="resultado">
        <div class="a">
            <img src="/img/op/claro.png" alt="Claro" title="Claro" />
            <div class="tel">(11) 97612 0592</div>
        </div>

        <div class="b">
            <p><span>Tipo <span>&raquo;</span></span> Celular</p>
            <p><span>Portabilidade <span>&raquo;</span></span> NÃ£o</p>
            <p><span>Estado <span>&raquo;</span></span> SÃ£o Paulo (SP)</p>
            <p><span>RegiÃ£o <span>&raquo;</span></span> SÃ£o Paulo e regiÃ£o metropolitana</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="li" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Consulta', 'Ligar'); window.location = 'tel:011976120592'">Ligar</button>
    <button class="nc" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Consulta', 'Nova'); window.location = '/'">Nova Consulta</button>
</div>
```

No caso eu só gostaria desse retorno em JSON.

```
<div class="resultado">
        <div class="a">
            <img src="/img/op/claro.png" alt="Claro" title="Claro" />
            <div class="tel">(11) 97612 0592</div>
        </div>

        <div class="b">
            <p><span>Tipo <span>&raquo;</span></span> Celular</p>
            <p><span>Portabilidade <span>&raquo;</span></span> NÃ£o</p>
            <p><span>Estado <span>&raquo;</span></span> SÃ£o Paulo (SP)</p>
            <p><span>RegiÃ£o <span>&raquo;</span></span> SÃ£o Paulo e regiÃ£o metropolitana</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Poderia informar o resultado da busca (formato .. etc ...)

Comment: Não.... eu quero que você coloque na sua pergunta o resultado que você está recebendo da sua consulta. Porque não conseguimos adivinhar como está vindo o retorno da requisição, Isso ajuda a todos a entender melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Ok, realizei as alterações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A página `http://consultanumero.info/consulta` não retorna um objeto json do php, em vez disso retorna no formato `text/html`. Então você deve percorrer o documento html retornado, procurar os elementos (tags que você quer) e pegar seus valores (conteudo). 
O exemplo a seguir (baseado no seu código) faz essas operações. Coloquei os comentarios no proprio codigo para facilitar o entendimento. Mas de forma geral a string retornada ao acessar a url é convertida em um objeto da classe [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.loadhtml.php), e a partir dela são acessados os nos do documento html.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//numero de teste
$post = ['tel' => '21996787878' , 'bto' => 'submit'];

$ch = curl_init('http://consultanumero.info/consulta');

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'http://consultanumero.info/consulta',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
    ],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS
]); 

//pagina html com a resposta
$output = curl_exec($ch);

/************************************************************
A partir da variavel $output, deve-se procurar as informações
relevantes do html
************************************************************/

//loadHTML retorna um objeto representando o DOM do arquivo html
$documento = DOMDocument::loadHTML($output);
//retorna um Objeto DOMListNode, que é composto por obejetos 
// DOMElement (que representam cada elemento do html com a tag <p>)
$tags = $documento->getElementsByTagName('p');

//array para montar o objeto json a ser retornado pelo script atual
$campos_json = [];

//a variavel $tag representa um objeto DOMElement (uma tag do documento html) 
//de onde pode-se obter os filhos dessa tag
foreach($tags as $tag){
    //como a variavel $tags tem paragrafos que não possui a mesma hierarquia que os paragrafos com as informações buscadas,
    //checar se esses atributos existem
    if($tag->firstChild !== null && 
        $tag->lastChild !== null){
        if($tag->firstChild->firstChild !== null){
            $chave = trim($tag->firstChild->firstChild->nodeValue);
            $valor = trim($tag->lastChild->nodeValue);
            $campos_json[$chave] = $valor;
        }
    }
}

//imprime resultado final em json
echo json_encode($campos_json);
```

O codigo acima gera como saida:

```
{"Tipo":"Celular","Portabilidade":"N\u00e3o","Estado":"Rio de Janeiro (RJ)","Regi\u00e3o":"Rio de Janeiro e regi\u00e3o metropolitana"}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!